# iTerm login error message about docker daemon

Tags: docker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry78p.png)

I know I had done some error operations about docker. Now, when I open a new window in iTerm, there is error message every time. It's `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

Comment: So is the docker daemon running or not? :)

Comment: Daemon is not running. Actually, when daemon is running, it's Ok. But, when I close daemon, it will be this error message. So how can I fix this problem even though there is no daemon. It's terrible that I will meet this error message every time when I open a new window in iTerm.